# Entity Framework Core SaveChangesAsync throwing TempValuePersists exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a strange problem. I am using EF Core 7 (latest). I am saving a set of related entities with the following code. In the code below `ContractSnapshotId` is the foreign key that I know is correct.

```
var originalProjectRoles = await (from o in _context.QuoteRoles.Include(m => m.RoleQuantities)
                                  where o.ContractId == id
                                  select o)
                                 .AsNoTracking()
                                 .ToListAsync();
        
var projectRoles = (from o in originalProjectRoles 
                    select new QuoteOrContractRole
                           {
                               ContractSnapshotId = contractSnapshot.Id,
                               ProjectRoleId = o.ProjectRoleId,
                               ExternalPerson = o.ExternalPerson,
                               ExternalVendor = o.ExternalVendor,
                               RoleType = o.RoleType,
                               UnitCost = o.UnitCost,
                               UnitPrice = o.UnitPrice,
                               ADUserId = o.ADUserId,
                           }).ToList();

await _context.QuoteRoles.AddRangeAsync(projectRoles);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

There are 56 entries being saved and all 56 entries are saved to the database.

However, one of the entries does not have its primary key (`Id`) updated from a temporary value, so EF is throwing an error.

The data looks like:

[image]

[image]

When I call `SaveChagesAsync()` and it gets to the `AcceptAllChanges()` after the data is written to the database, one of the entries does not have its primary key updated (even though it is actually in the database).

The `changedEntries` collection looks like this:

[image]

The 13th entry still has a temporary value. I can't understand how the data is in the database, but the primary key has not been read back from the database for this one entry.

Can someone point me in the right direction, as there is absolutely no indication of why this is happening.

Comment: EF doesn't use temporary values AFAIK for keys, so what logic is populating these are determining if/when to replace these? Is EF & the database set up to use an Identity column for the PK? This smells like a customized DbContext trying to handle temporary PKs and something is getting mixed up. (what looks like juggling FKs between Contract, ContractSnapshot, and Quotes is also scary :)

Comment: Well if you look at the source of EF Core 7 the negative key numbers are treated like temporary values.  I am not doing anything special with keys, it is a very basic EF implementation.  There is no juggling of keys.  The foreign key that i am using is for a record that i just saved to the DB in a previous call that was left out for brevity.